# Bootstrap navbar not aligning responsively when veiwing on other devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, navbar

I've been coding a navbar for my personal portfolio website and it looks great on a computer screen but when i open it on a mobile device the menu items tend to stack horizontally and just generally go out of line, how can i get this to look nice on all devices? I'm pretty new to coding so any help would be appreciated!

https://codepen.io/Bowdoo95/pen/PJzZVp

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <nav id="nav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
        <a id="name" href="#"><b>Joseph Bowditch</b></h5></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7">
        <ul id="menu-items" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="active"><a class="home" href="#page-one"><b>Home</b></a></li>
          <li><a class="portfolio" href="#page-two"><b>Portfolio</b></a></li>
          <li><a class="about-me" href="#page-three"><b>About Me</b></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
        <a href="#page-four" id="contact-me" class="btn navbar-btn" role="button"><b>Contact Me</b></a>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#name{
  color:#FFF;
  float:left;
  padding-top:5%;
}
#nav{
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color:transparent;
  margin: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a{
  color:#FFF;
  padding-top:18px;
}
.navbar-btn{
  border: 3px solid #FFF;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  background-color:transparent;
  color:#FFF;
  float:right;
}
#menu-items{
  margin-right:-100px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using bootstrap's navigation bar and trying to override it. But seems like you over "override" it ;-). I've modified couple things in your css file. Have a look at those changes and have some idea to solve your issue. You can make changes accordingly in your css. Below is codepen link. Thanks.

```
"https://codepen.io/kapu9899/pen/JrbMmB"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty new to bootstrap as well! I would suggest switching to the navbar toggler, and collapse modes for mobile: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#toggler
There are some good examples in the documentation there that you can pretty much copy, paste and modify.

And I agree with Kalpesh Patel that there is some overstyling going on. While I am new I think having two break point definitions for your columns that are identically sized might be redundant. The documentation is really useful check out the one on breakpoints and change your screen size to test out their examples : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#all-breakpoints.

Also Blackrock Digital has some really useful templates for full websites on their github account.

Best,